# How to convert a date string to different format

Tags: python, date, datetime, strptime, strftime

I need to convert date **string** "2013-1-25" to **string** "1/25/13" in python.
I looked at the `datetime.strptime` but still can't find a way for this.

Comment: You can use dateutil.parser.parse() function which converts random strings to datetime object without specifying their input formats

Answer (score 297, accepted):

I assume I have `import datetime` before running each of the lines of code below

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-1-25", '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

prints `"01/25/13"`.

If you can't live with the leading zero, try this:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-1-25", '%Y-%m-%d')
print '{0}/{1}/{2:02}'.format(dt.month, dt.day, dt.year % 100)
```

This prints `"1/25/13"`.

EDIT: This may not work on every platform:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-1-25", '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

Answer (score 31):

If you can live with 01 for January instead of 1, then try...

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-1-25", '%Y-%m-%d')
print datetime.date.strftime(d, "%m/%d/%y")
```

You can check the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for other formatting directives.