# remove special character '-' from date format (integer) in python

Tags: python

I want to remove special character '-' from date format in python. I have retrieved maximum date from a database column.
Here is my small code:

```
def max_date():
    Max_Date= hive_select('SELECT  MAX (t_date) FROM ovisto.ovisto_log')
    value = Max_Date[0]
print value
```

Here is output:

```
{0: '2017-02-21', '_c0': '2017-02-21'}
```

I want only numbers without special character '-' from output.
so, I am expecting this answer '20170221'

I have tried in different ways but could not get proper answer.
How can I get in a simple way? Thanks for your time.

Comment: What about `Max_Date[0] = Max_Date[0].replace('-','')`.

Comment: have tried in different ways <- such as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just rebuild a new dictionary using dict comprehension, iterating on the original dictionary, and stripping the unwanted characters from values using `str.replace`

```
d = {0: '2017-02-21', '_c0': '2017-02-21'}

new_d = {k:v.replace("-","") for k,v in d.items()}

print(new_d)
```

result:

```
{0: '20170221', '_c0': '20170221'}
```

if you only want to keep the values and drop the duplicates (and the order too :), use a set comprehension with the values instead:

```
s = {v.replace("-","") for _,v in d.items()}
```

Comment: hello jean it works perfectly but i just want single value  '20170221'. Do you have any idea how can I select a value from a key or index of value ?

Comment: you mean you need uniqueness of values and drop the keys?

Comment: ya, sort of because when I retrive a max date it gives me two values with two keys. '0' and '_c0' with same date. So, want single value '20170221' without key.

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested but why it gives me `set(['20170221'])`  instead '20170221' ?

Comment: @ Jean thanks a lot for your help.  I got it now. ` r = {v.replace("-","") for _,v in value.items()}` gives `set(['20170221'])`  further, `s = ''.join(x for x in r if x.isdigit())` and    `int(s)` gives me desired output `20170221`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try strptime:

```
value = Max_Date[0]
new_val= datetime.datetime.strptime( str( value ), '%Y%m%d').strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

I found it here: [How to convert a date string to different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524322/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-different-format)