# In python how to change date format in a csv?

Tags: python, csv, date

I am trying to change the format of dates from `30-Jan-02` to `30.Jan.2002` occurring in second position in a csv file using python.
I tried several things but I am confused with strings and bytes comptability.

```
import os 
import csv 


from datetime import datetime
import sys
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

with open("Filenamecsv",'r') as csvfile, NamedTemporaryFile(dir="path/parh",delete=False) as temp:
    w = csv.writer(temp)
    r = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in r:
        dt = row[2].split("-")
        row[2] = "{}.{}.{}".format(row[-1],row[1],row[0])
        w.writerow(row)
move(temp.name,"Filename.csv")
```

Comment: What is the exact problem with your code? Do you get an error message?

Comment: What is the problem you facing?

Comment: If your date is in the second position it should be in ``row[1]``. And if it's in the form ``30-Jan-02`` then why do you split with ``/``? And when you build your new date you want to use ``dt`` instead of ``row`` in ``"{}.{}.{}".format(...)``.

Comment: these are the errors I get : '
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'strftime'
   TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'``@MrLeeh @MONTYHS thanks !

Comment: Your error makes no sense, since you're not calling ``strftime`` anywhere in your sample code - and your sample code does not use DataFrame objects either. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Maybe because I didnt save my changes , I just relauched it and I got: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_erg_data.py", line 25, in <module>
    w.writerow(row)
  File "/Users/edouardblondel/anaconda/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 483, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str''

Comment: You have to look at this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524322/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-different-format

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `datetime`

```
In [25]: import datetime

In [26]: dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("30-Jan-02", '%d-%b-%y').strftime('%d.%b.%Y')

In [27]: dt
Out[27]: '30.Jan.2002'
```

Answer (score 1):

iterable unpacking

```
day, month, year = row[2].split('-')
```

conditional expression, assuming your dates won't be into the future...

```
year = ('19' if int(year)>17 else '20')+year
```

replacing into `row`

```
row[2] = '.'.join((day, month, year))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is an extension to above mentioned answer and self explanatory.

```
import datetime

with open("filename.csv", 'r') as csvfile, open('temp.csv', 'w') as temp_file:

    for line in csvfile.readlines():
        # Fetch all dates in the csv
        dates = line.split(',')

        # Extract date, month and year
        dt, mon, yr = dates[1].split('-')

        # Convert the second date and replace
        dates[1] = datetime.datetime.strptime(dates[1], '%d-%b-%y').strftime('%d.%b.%Y')

        # Write date to temp file
        temp_file.write(','.join(dates))

print("Process complete!")
```

Input: filename.csv

```
30-Jan-02,31-Jan-02,01-Feb-02
30-Jan-02,31-Jan-02,01-Feb-02
```

Output: temp.csv

```
30-Jan-02,31.Jan.2002,01-Feb-02
30-Jan-02,31.Jan.2002,01-Feb-02
```