# PYTHON > Rearrange item data ("date") within .csv file

Tags: python, csv

**Source csv:**

```
column a, column b, 2021-01-09, column d
column a, column b, 2021-01-10, column d
column a, column b, 2021-01-11, column d
```

**Desired output:**

```
09/01/2021, column a, column b, column d
10/01/2021, column a, column b, column d
11/01/2021, column a, column b, column d
```

What is the best method to achieve this, pythonically?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your row from the csv is like

```
row = ["column a", "column b", "2021-01-09", "column d"]
```

you can do something like

```
import datetime

row.sort()
row[0] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d/%m/%y')
```

gives row as

```
>>> row
['09/01/21', 'column a', 'column b', 'column d']
```

Comment: Thanks @Jarvis for your concise answer!

Answer (score 1):

One way with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/getting_started.html) to achieve that as you already have answer's using **csv.DictWriter**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('source.csv',names=["ColA", "ColB", "Date", "ColD"])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.strip(), format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
new_df = df[['Date', 'ColA', 'ColB', 'ColD']]
print(new_df)
```

**Output:**

```
         Date      ColA       ColB       ColD
0  09/01/2021  column a   column b   column d
1  10/01/2021  column a   column b   column d
2  11/01/2021  column a   column b   column d
```

Comment: glad it helps you somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

**Reordering, as per:**
[Python - re-ordering columns in a csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001490/python-re-ordering-columns-in-a-csv)

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as infile, open('reordered.csv', 'a') as outfile:
    fieldnames = ['column c', 'column a', 'column b', 'column d']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

**Adding dates:**
[In python how to change date format in a csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045643/in-python-how-to-change-date-format-in-a-csv)

```
import datetime

with open("reordered.csv", 'r') as csvfile, open('file.csv', 'w') as temp_file:

    for line in csvfile.readlines():
        # Fetch all dates in the csv
        dates = line.split(',')

        # Extract date, month and year
        yr, mon, dt = dates[0].split('-')

        # Convert the second date and replace
        dates[0] = datetime.datetime.strptime(dates[0], '%y-%b-%d').strftime('%d/%b/%Y')

        # Write date to temp file
        temp_file.write(','.join(dates))
```