# How to change date format of a date inside a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string "Hello please change the date from 04/24/2017 by putting month in the middle"

```
class Paragraph:

    @staticmethod
    def change_date_format(paragraph):
        return None

print(Paragraph.change_date_format('Hello please change the date from 04-24-2017 by putting month in the middle'))
```

I need to change this to "Hello please change the date from 24/04/2017 by putting month in the middle"

Comment: Not clear what the problem might be

Comment: Please refer the link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524322/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-different-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524322/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-different-format)

Comment: I have a sentence which has "Hello today is 07/14/2017". I have to change this to "Hello today is 14/07/2017". @Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
def change_date_format(paragraph):
    return re.sub('(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)', 
        lambda m: '{}/{}/{}'.format(m.group(2), m.group(1), m.group(3)), 
        paragraph)
```

This finds a sequence of three groups of digits separated by slashes (like 04/27/2017), then uses `format` to swap the first and second group.

Comment: Please add an explanation for your code.

Comment: @bfontaine I thought it's rather self-explaining.

Comment: If someone doesn’t know `re.sub` nor `lambda` it’s not.

Answer (score -1):

datetime can do this:

```
import datetime
def change_date_format(date):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```