# How to format a date string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I have a DateTime passed in from an external C# program to my python script in the following format:

```
2019-08-22 11:00:25.671640+00:00
```

But I have a python library that expects it in this format:

```
2019-08-21 17:04:36.501
```

How can I format the input string to this format always in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a date string to different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524322/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-different-format)

Comment: That "+00:00" is the time zone.  If the input time zone is always zero, that's OK, but do you have to worry about different time zones?

Comment: simply slice the string till milliseconds.
str = str[:26]
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

```
date = '2019-08-22 11:00:25.671640+00:00'
date_new = date.split('.')[0]
```

output

```
'2019-08-22 11:00:25'
```

if you need precision up to microseconds:

```
date_new=date.split('.')[0] + '.' + date.split('.')[1][:3]
```

output:

```
2019-08-22 11:00:25.671
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) covers this in depth.

Assuming that you've got an actual `datetime` object called `dt`, to get the format you want you'd do

```
 timestamp = "{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%S.%f}".format(dt)[:-3]
```

Python doesn't support millisecond resolution, so

```
timestamp = "{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%S.%f}".format(dt)
```

would give you `2019-08-21 17:04:36.501XXX`. And then to take only the millisecond part you take the whole string, except the last three characters.