# How to convert date string to string format in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

Im reading in an excel file in python with multiple sheets called CL,PPU,TC and FI. Im looking to change the date format for multiple columns in these sheets from yyyy-mm-dd to dd/mm/yyyy. I am aware of similar posts to this question on here([How to convert a date string to different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524322/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-different-format)), but I am new to python and just trying to get my head around how to define it for each column or the whole sheet etc

Comment: Could you please provide some dummy data and your code so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)