# How do I perform the below datetime operation?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date with format in 'yyyy-dd-mm'. How do I convert to 'yyyy-mm-dd' format, been bit of a struggle with strftime and strptime!

Assuming the date is '1919-01-12', I want to see it in the format '1919-12-01'.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"bit of a struggle"*? Give a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a date string to different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524322/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-different-format)

Comment: @miquelvir yes that was helpful as well ! thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
import datetime
print (datetime.datetime.strptime("1919-01-12", "%Y-%d-%m").strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime

date = '1919-01-12'
formatted_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%d-%m').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

`datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%d-%m')` creates a datetime object from a string, `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` formats the datetime as a string accoring to the specified pattern