# convert time format from '20210730T220000Z' to the format '2021-07-30T00:00'

Tags: python, json, datetime-format, icalendar, taskwarrior

I'm using taskwarrior as a task manager and want to convert task into event for my calender in a `.ics`fformat (ICal) using python (`ics` package).

if I run the following code:

```
from ics import Calendar, Event
import json
task1 = {'description': 'blabla', 'scheduled': '20210730T220000Z' }
task2 = {'description': 'blabla', 'scheduled': '2021-07-30T00:00' }

task = task1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Calendar()
    print(task)
    e = Event()
    e.name = task['description']
    e.begin = task['scheduled']
    c.events.add(e)
```

it throws me an error:

```
arrow.parser.ParserError: Could not match input to any of ['YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm'] on '20210730T220000Z'
```

There is no problem if I replace `task = task1` by `task = task2`. I suspect that the format of the JSON with timezone is not supported by `ics`. Is there an easy way / package to convert `20210730T220000Z` to the format `2021-07-30T00:00`?

**Edit N°1**
After the comment of @mkrieger1 and the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524322/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-different-format) I tried the following without success:

```
import datetime
task1 = {'description': 'blabla', 'scheduled': '20210730T220000Z' }
task2 = {'description': 'blabla', 'scheduled': '2021-07-30T00:00' }
print(task1["scheduled"])
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(task1["scheduled"], 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm').strftime('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm')
print(dt)
```

**Edit N°2**: this finally worked:

```
import datetime
task1 = {'description': 'blabla', 'scheduled': '20210730T220000Z' }
task2 = {'description': 'blabla', 'scheduled': '2021-07-30T00:00' }
print(task1["scheduled"])
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(task1["scheduled"], "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S%fZ")
print(dt)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a date string to different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524322/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-different-format)

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @mkrieger1. I editet the question accordingly but could not solve the problem

Comment: You didn't use the date format specifiers correctly. Use them as shown in the answers I've linked and as explained here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse date string and change format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265357/parse-date-string-and-change-format)

Comment: yes (linked in the first link of mkrieger1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time format `20210730T220000Z` is known as ["ISO 8601 basic format"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles):

> Representations can be done in one of two formats – a basic format with a minimal number of separators or an extended format with separators added to enhance human readability.

There are different formats such as RFC3339 and ISO8601, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65221179) discusses their relationship in detail. But this error you're seeing is not due to the presence of a timezone (`Z` for UTC).

Arrow has recently added support in [v0.15](https://github.com/arrow-py/arrow/releases/tag/0.15.0):

> [NEW] ISO 8601 basic format for dates and times is now supported (e.g. YYYYMMDDTHHmmssZ).

The [latest version of `ics` is 0.7](https://pypi.org/project/ics/#history) (that you are likely using), as of this writing.
It [pins `arrow` to <0.15](https://github.com/ics-py/ics-py/blob/v0.7/requirements.txt#L2), which directly explains and reproduces the error you're seeing.

To move forward, you have a few options:

1. Manually handle datetime format parsing, whether by using `arrow`, `dateutil`, `datetime`, as already suggested by @mrkrieger1. `ics` gives us a [convenient escape hatch](https://github.com/ics-py/ics-py/blob/v0.7/ics/utils.py#L191-L192) to `arrow`:

   ```py
   e.begin = task['scheduled'], 'YYYYMMDDTHHmmssZ'
   ```

   This corresponds to the [two string parameter form](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=get#creation), e.g. `arrow.get('2013-05-05 12:30:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`
2. Use an unreleased version of `ics`, which has new developments and no longer depends on `arrow`. If newer `ics` doesn't handle it, at least you're free to use the latest `arrow` package.
3. Add another datetime parsing library, of your choice (`pendulum`, `dateutil`, etc.). The whole datetime handling situation can be messy in Python but they all tend to interoperate with stdlib `datetime`.