# How to split date and format it

Tags: python

I already figured out how to split the name from the date from a imported text file. I am trying to figure out how I could change the date from a mm/dd/yyyy format into month, date, yyyy.

This is the code I have to separate the names from the date:
`with open("dates.txt",'r') as data_file: for line in data_file: data = line.split(',')`
would I have to do an import such as datetime or pandas?

and here is how the first line of the text file looks like:
Richard Alexander,12/21/1995

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a date string to different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524322/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-different-format)

Comment: What do you want to do with the changed data after?

Comment: I wanted to write the new data into a new file with the name and the changed date.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the desired output for the date format? Do you want 12/21/1995 -> 12,  21, 1995 or December, 21, 1995?

Comment: it would be December, 21, 1995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import datetime


def format_to_format(raw_date: str, source_format: str, target_format: str) -> str:
    """
    :raw_date: source date string
    :source_format: source date string format e.g '%m/%d/%Y'
    :target_format: e.g '%m-%d-%Y'

    :return: formatted date string
    """
    date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(raw_date, source_format)
    result = date_obj.strftime(target_format)
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("dates.txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in f.read().splitlines():
            print(line)
            raw_date = line.split(',')[1]
            date = format_to_format(raw_date, '%m/%d/%Y', '%m, %d, %Y')
            print(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well youd have to use 2 different python functions.
One is `split` like so:

```
Dates = line.split('/')
```

And then use `join` like so :

```
','.join(Dates)
```

Of course youll need to iterate over it in a four loop beacuse you get  a lot of 3 close elements as a single date, or even better after splitting each line join it to a different variable,
Hope it helped:)

Answer (score 0):

Standard modules like
[csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)
and [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)
are your friend!

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
import datetime as dt


def parse(fin):
    fmt = "%B, %d, %Y,"  # Month, date, yyyy
    sheet = csv.reader(fin)
    for name, date in sheet:
        date = dt.datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
        print(date.strftime(fmt), name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse(StringIO("Richard Alexander,12/21/1995"))
```

output:

```
December, 21, 1995, Richard Alexander
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```py
from datetime import datetime 

name_and_date = "Richard Alexander,12/21/1995"
name, date_str = name_and_date.split(",")

date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%m/%d/%Y")
formatted_date = date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")

print(f"{name},{formatted_date}")
```

---

```
Richard Alexander,December 21, 1995
```

But when written to csv, the date will be automatically wrapped in quotes like so:
`Richard Alexander,"December 21, 1995"`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import calendar

with open("dates.txt",'r') as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        data = line.split(',')
        date = data[1].split('/')
        data[1] = f"{calendar.month_name[int(date[0])]}, {date[1]}, {date[2]}"
        # write data to a new file here
```

Answer (score 0):

Using standard libraries to parse and reformat the time and handle a CSV correctly:

```py
import csv
import datetime as dt

# Never use the default encoding.  It's OS-specific.
# newline='' is a documented requirement for csv.reader/writer.
with (open('input.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='') as fin,
      open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as fout):
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for data in reader:
        d = dt.datetime.strptime(data[1], '%m/%d/%Y')
        data[1] = d.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
        writer.writerow(data)
```

input.csv:

```
Richard Alexander,12/21/1995
John Smith,1/2/2002
Kilroy Washere,5/10/2010
```

output.csv:

```
Richard Alexander,"December 21, 1995"
John Smith,"January 02, 2002"
Kilroy Washere,"May 10, 2010"
```

Using `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', encoding='utf8', header=None, parse_dates=[1])
df.to_csv('output.csv', encoding='utf8', index=False, header=None, date_format='%B %d, %Y')
```

(same output)

See Also: [Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)