# How to add leading zeros and convert my date field to YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have some dates in my json file that look like this:

```
2020-12-11
2020-5-1
2020-3-21
```

and I want to convert them to `YYYY-MM-DD` format. They are already in a similar format, but I want to add leading zeros for single-digit month and day numbers.

The output should look like this:

```
2020-12-11
2020-05-01
2020-03-21
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please clarify the issue? These already seem to be YYYY-MM-DD ordered. Are you looking for padding, e.g. translate `5` to `05`? Are they actually in YDM order?

Comment: The input is not enirely clear, I assume you mean that input is in YYYY-DD-MM format, which you could convert with `datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-12-11", "%Y-%d-%m").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`.

Comment: this "2020-5-1" is not in YYYY-MM-DD fromat, and yes, the final date should look like this : "2020-05-01"

Comment: _is not in YYYY-MM-DD fromat_: please update your question accordingly instead of having the readers guess ...

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear about the input format.

Comment: @mkrieger is it month-day or day-month?

Comment: According to the given examples, and the title, month-day.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The examples are ambiguous and both the title and text only say what the target format is.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that 5 should be mapped to 05, and 1 to 01, not 5 to 01 and 1 to 05.

Answer (score 1):

The parser in datetutil can be used as follows (`d1` is original date string):

```
from dateutil import parser
d2 = parser.parse(d1).date()
```

produces (datetime format which could be converted to string using strftime() if that is required):

```
2020-12-11
2020-05-01
2020-03-21
```

There is also an option (`dayfirst = True`) to declare day-before-month.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to reformat a date string is to use the `datetime` module (see [How to convert a date string to different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524322/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-different-format)).

Here you want to use the format codes (quoting the descriptions from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes))

> - `%Y` - Year with century as a decimal number.
> - `%m` - Month as a zero-padded decimal number.
> - `%d` - Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.

According to the footnote (9) in the documentation of `datetime`, `%m` and `%d` accept month and day numbers without leading zeros when used with `strptime`, but will output zero-padded numbers when used with `strftime`.

So you can use the same format string `%Y-%m-%d` to do a round-trip with `strptime` and `strftime` to add the zero-padding.

```
from datetime import datetime

def reformat(date_str):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, fmt).strftime(fmt)
```